# I am new to React Native and tryng to figure out how to use custom fonts in my app, this is the error im getting:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo

The Error: (it only appeared after I added the font rlated code (e.g. imported from `"expo-font"`  and `AppLoading` from `"expo"` , started usng the `Font.loadAsync()` function))

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

The App.js component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';

const customFonts = {
  comic: require('./assets/fonts/RampartOne-Regular.ttf'),
};

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('ass');
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('');
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  const _loadFonts = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
    setFontLoaded(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    _loadFonts();
  });

  const handlePress = () => {
    setList((prev) => {
      const el = { val: current, key: count };
      return [...prev, el];
    });
    setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
    setCurrent('');
    console.log(list);
  };
  const handleChange = (val) => {
    setCurrent(val);
  };

  const fullList = list.length ? (
    list.map((obj) => {
      return (
        <Text key={obj.key} style={styles.ass}>
          {obj.val}
        </Text>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <Text></Text>
  );

  const fullFlatList = list.length ? (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item) => {
        return item.key.toString();
      }}
      style={styles.body}
      data={list}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        <Text style={styles.ass}>{item.val}</Text>;
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <Text></Text>
  );

  if (fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => {
            return item.key.toString();
          }}
          style={styles.body}
          data={list}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return <Text style={styles.ass}>{item.val}</Text>;
          }}
        />
        <View style={styles.inputs}>
          <TextInput
            value={current}
            onChangeText={handleChange}
            placeholder='input something to change the title'
          />
          <Button title='cum' onPress={handlePress} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  } else if (!fontLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }
}

const styles = {
  body: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    fontFamily: 'comic',
  },
  wrapper: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
  },
  ass: {
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    overflow: 'visible',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  inputs: {
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
};
```

Comment: It seems the problam is with the `AppLoading` component, but you havent' shared that. As the error message says, you likely either forgot to export it or exported it with `export default`, in which case your import is wrong - it should not use the curly braces

Comment: Check renderItem in Fullflatlist. It’s missing a return.

Comment: @idmean I fixed it so now its returning the <Text><Text/> component but it didnt resolve the issue.

Comment: @robin-zigmond  AppLoading was not written by me since Im exporting it from the "expo" module so I cant share the code for it but I did try to change the import statement to `import AppLoading from "expo"` which didnt resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I should have spotted that. I'm not familiar with the library but from looking at the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/) it appears you should import it as `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'`, rather than the way you've done it here.

Comment: @robin-zigmond ty, i was following along an old tutorial and apparantly they showed a deprecated way of importing the module, installing expo-app-loading seperatly and importing it like that resolved everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way to load custom fonts

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located. Then inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Inside `useFonts.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";
 
export default useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'comic': require('./assets/fonts/RampartOne-Regular.ttf'),
  });
```

Now in your `App.js` write like this

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return <View styles={styles.container}>{/* Code Here */}</View>;
}
```